# Capcom driver vulnerability: Bluescreens on the physical PC, but not in the virtual machine

Tags: windows, winapi, kernel, exploit, windows-kernel

I am investigating anti-cheat mechanisms in computer games using the popular Capcom driver with a vulnerability.

You can pass user mode functions to the Capcom driver via DeviceIoControl() calls, which are then executed in kernel context.

Now I'm faced with a strange problem:

I run the DeviceIoControl() calls as they are also successfully executed by many others.
In my virtual machine the DeviceIoControl() calls also work without problems.
However, when I execute the code on my physical PC, I get a blue screen with the message "SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION".

Here is the code that works correctly in the VM, but not on my physical PC:

```
void __stdcall EmptyTestFunction(MmGetSystemRoutineAddress_t pMmGetSystemRoutineAddress, PVOID userData) {

}
DriverLoadingTest() {
    HANDLE device = OpenDevice("Htsysm72FB");

    CapcomCodePayload* codePayload = (CapcomCodePayload*)VirtualAlloc(nullptr, sizeof(CapcomCodePayload), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    BYTE codePayloadBuf[] = {
        0xE8, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,                               // CALL $+8 ; Skip 8 bytes, this puts the UserFunction into RAX
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,             // UserFunction address will be here
        0x48, 0xBA, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // MOV RDX, userData
        0x58,                                                       // POP RAX
        0xFF, 0x20                                                  // JMP [RAX]
    };

    *(ULONGLONG*)(codePayloadBuf + 5) = (ULONGLONG)EmptyTestFunction;
    *(ULONGLONG*)(codePayloadBuf + 15) = (ULONGLONG)0;

    codePayload->pointerToPayload = codePayload->payload;

    ZeroMemory(codePayload->payload, PAYLOAD_BUFFER_SIZE);
    CopyMemory(codePayload->payload, codePayloadBuf, sizeof(codePayloadBuf));

    status = 0x0;
    DWORD bytesReturned = 0x0;
    DeviceIoControl(device, IOCTL_RunPayload64, &codePayload->pointerToPayload, sizeof(ULONG_PTR), &status, sizeof(status), &bytesReturned, 0);
    printf("DeviceIoControl returned %08x\n", status);
}
```

I only make limited progress with the crash dump because I lack experience.
The crash happens every time the following instruction is executed:

```
mov cr4, rax
```

With rax=0000000000070678

The exception code is: c0000096

I hang the WinDbg "!analyze -v" crash dump at the end of my post.

My main concern is to find out how I could tackle the problem now in order to solve it. Because the situation that the exact same code works in the VM, but not on my physical PC, is completely new to me.

[link to crash dump](https://pastebin.com/Z35HveSu)

Answer (score 1):

CR4 is one of the x86 [control registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_register) and you are clearly glomming something in there which is causing a CPU exception.

That register consists of a set of flag bits as documented [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_register#cr4), so let's look at which ones you are setting:

0x70678 = 1110000011001111000b, so we have the following:

```
0   VME Virtual 8086 Mode Extensions - OFF (sounds OK)
1   PVI Protected-mode Virtual Interrupts - OFF
2   TSD Time Stamp Disable - OFF
3   DE  Debugging Extensions - ON
4   PSE Page Size Extension - ON
5   PAE Physical Address Extension - ON
6   MCE Machine Check Exception- ON
7   PGE Page Global Enabled - OFF
8   PCE Performance-Monitoring Counter enable - OFF
9   OSFXSR  Operating system support for FXSAVE and FXRSTOR instructions - ON
10  OSXMMEXCPT  Operating System Support for Unmasked SIMD Floating-Point Exceptions - ON
11  UMIP    User-Mode Instruction Prevention - OFF
12  LA57    (none specified) - OFF
13  VMXE    Virtual Machine Extensions Enable - OFF
14  SMXE    Safer Mode Extensions Enable - OFF
16  FSGSBASE    Enables the instructions RDFSBASE, RDGSBASE, WRFSBASE, and WRGSBASE - ON
17  PCIDE   PCID Enable - ON
18  OSXSAVE XSAVE and Processor Extended States Enable - ON
20  SMEP[4] Supervisor Mode Execution Protection Enable - OFF
21  SMAP    Supervisor Mode Access Prevention Enable - OFF
22  PKE Protection Key Enable - OFF
```

So one of these is upsetting the apple cart, and my money would be on bits 4 and / or 5.

HOWEVER.  Why is the code trying to set CR4 at all?  I can't think of a single reason why you would want to do that *in kernel mode*, unless you are part of the OS. *Which you are not*.

Anyway, I hope that gives you something to go on.  I dislike the question though because there is nowhere near enough context and have therefore voted to close (although I didn't vote it down because it does hold some interest for me).

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that Hyper-V hypervisor prohibited writing to register CR4, which led to the bluescreens.

I don't know if this is specifically because I am accessing the kernel from the Capcom driver. Other kernel modules will probably also access the CR4 register? If yes, then it is specifically related to the Capcom driver. So if someone has the same problem, they should check if they have enabled the Hyper-V Hypervisor service.